# How to add customised button in GWT dataGrid?

Tags: gwt

I want one column full of buttons[my own customised button] and want to have clickhandlers for those button in my application ? How to Create the code?

Thanks

---

Cell cell = new AbstractCell()
    {

```
    @Override
    public void render( com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb )
    {
        FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
        custombutton tb = new custombutton ("click");
        tb.setText( value );
        fp.add( tb );
        sb.appendHtmlConstant( fp.getElement().getString() );
    }
};
// Address.
Column<ContactInfo, String> addressColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, String>( cell )
{
    @Override
    public String getValue( ContactInfo object )
    {
        return object.getAddress();
   }
```

This is my code, if the ContactInfo.getid() is true only i should create the button for that column but now its getting created for all columns? please suggest some idea?,

Comment: how about theese buttons. http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

Comment: I want to add customised Button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ActionCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ActionCell.html), and then apply CSS to it to make it look any way you like.

Look at GWT Showcase for an example of how to do it: http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

Comment: I want to add to my column only for certain conditions . so how to check the condition before adding cell to column. more over i want to use rounded button, so i have a customsed one, how do i use my customised button and write click handler for it?

Comment: 1. In GWT you never add handlers to buttons within a column - you simply override execute() in ActionCell. Look at the code in the Showcase example that I provided. 2. You can add or hide a column, and you can show or hide a button inside each individual cell based on any conditions that you like. 3. As I said, use CSS to make your button look anyway you like - rounded, with gradient, whatever.

Comment: pls provide a detailed one.especially how to get object and check condition before adding to column

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a similar functionality by creating a new custom cell which accepts a list of custom Action objects.

```
Action{
String id;
boolean clicked;
ClickHandler handler;
}

CustomCell extends AbstractCell<List<Action>>{
}
```

In the render method, I have created a button element having the 'id' value for each action object in the list of actions.

```
@Template("<button id=\"{0}\"></button>")
SafeHtml buttonHtml(String id);

public void render(Context context, List<Action> rowActions, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
   for(Action action: rowActions){
     sb.append(buttonHtml(action.getId()));
   }
}
```

In the onBrowserEvent, when a click happens, if it happens in the span element, we could get the id of that span element, and set the corresponding action object to clicked state.

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, List<Action> value, NativeEvent event,
    ValueUpdater<List<Action>> valueUpdater) {
  // Let AbstractCell handle the keydown event.
  super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);

  // Handle the click event.
  if ("click".equals(event.getType())) {
    // Ignore clicks that occur outside of the outermost element.
    EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();

    if (parent.isOrHasChild(Element.as(eventTarget))) {
        // if (parent.getFirstChildElement().isOrHasChild(
        // Element.as(eventTarget))) {

        // use this to get the selected element!!
        Element el = Element.as(eventTarget);

        // check if we really click on the image
        if (el.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("button")) {
            for(Action action:value){
                if(el.getAttribute("id").equals(action.getId())){
                    action.setClicked(true);
                }
            }
            doAction(value,
                    valueUpdater);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the value updater, based on the clicked state, action objects click handler method is invoked.

Comment: I created actioncell and it is working fine. But if i apply CSS it is applied to entire cell, not to button.pls help

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Column<VolunteerTO, VolunteerTO> createReissueButtonColumn(String columnName) {

    ActionCell<VolunteerTO> reListCell = new ActionCell<VolunteerTO>("Reissue", new ActionCell.Delegate<VolunteerTO>() {
                @Override
                public void execute(VolunteerTO object) {
                   // code to be executed 
                }
             }) 
         {
             @Override
             public void render(Cell.Context context,VolunteerTO value,SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
                 if(null != value.getVolunteerStatus()  && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(value.getVolunteerStatus())) {
                     super.render(context,value,sb);
                 }

             }


         };

         Column<VolunteerTO, VolunteerTO> reListColumn = new Column<VolunteerTO, VolunteerTO>(reListCell) {
              @Override
              public VolunteerTO getValue(VolunteerTO object) {
                return object;
              }
                public String getCellStyleNames(Cell.Context context, VolunteerTO object) {

                if(object.getVolunteerStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(GatesClientConstants.ISSUED)|| object.getVolunteerStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(GatesClientConstants.PROTECTED)){
                    return "myButtonStyle";
                }else if(object.getVolunteerStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(GatesClientConstants.ACCEPTED)|| object.getVolunteerStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(GatesClientConstants.RELEASED)){
                    return "btn_disable";
                }
                return "leftalign";

            }

         };
         reListColumn.setDataStoreName(columnName);
         reListColumn.setSortable(false);
    return reListColumn;

}
```

Comment: The CSS is applied for entire cell not to the Button?

Comment: .myButtonStyle;
.myButtonStyle {
        background-color:red;
}
.myButtonStyle TD button {

      background:#002A50;

      color: white;

      font-size: 5pt; !important;

      text-align: center;

      cursor: pointer;

      font-weight: normal;

      width: 15px; !important;

      height: 15px; !important;

}

@external .btn_disable;
.btn_disable {

      background:#002A50;

      color: gray;

      font-size: 5pt;!important;

      text-align: center;

      cursor: default;

      font-weight: normal;

      width: 15px;!important;

      height: 15px;!important;

}